# Exception handling and propagation Guava cache

Tags: java, caching, guava, callable

I have a cache implementation where in as a part of the Callable implementation (i.e. call method) I raise a Checked exception (sub-classsed from Exception). See the code snippet below. Is this is the right way of throwing a custom exception from the cache loading process ? Rest of my code is strongly dependent on the CustomCheckedException handling so I want to make sure that the approach below is the right way to go !! The method doSomething throws the CustomCheckedException.

```
public class ABiggerClass {

    ...

    private SomeClass getSomeData(ParamClass param) throws CustomCheckedException {

        SomeClass d = null;
        try {
            d = someCache.get(getCacheKey(),
                    new CacheLoader(param));
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Throwables.propagateIfInstanceOf(e.getCause(),
                    CustomCheckedException.class);
        }

        return d;
    }

    private class CacheLoader implements Callable<SomeClass> {

        private ParamClass param;

        @Override
        public SomeClass call() throws Exception {

            SomeClass result = new SomeClass();

            result.doSomething(param);

            return result;
        }

        public CacheLoader(ParamClass param) {
            super();
            this.param = param;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: This question might be better on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645965/guava-cache-and-preserving-checked-exceptions